# How to send nested json objects inside a request body

Tags: java, android, android-volley

how can i send  this request in the body of my volley request,
thanks in advance

```
{
  "amount": "000",
  "card": {
    "number": "00000",
    "expiry_month": "00",
    "expiry_year": "00",
    "cvv": "000",
    "pin": "000"
  }
}
```

this is my request parameters, i have try this the api is tell me invalid parametes, please guzs help me

```
 @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Authorization", User_Token);
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json";
        }



        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put( "amount", amount);
            params.put( "card", String.valueOf(come()));

            return new JSONObject(params).toString().getBytes();
        }
        private byte[] come() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put( "number", number);
            params.put( "expiry_month", month);
            params.put( "expiry_year", year);
            params.put( "cvv", cvv);
            params.put( "pin", pin);
            return new JSONObject(params).toString().getBytes();
        }
```

Comment: Specify which API gives you an error? It's server response or what? Also specify an error itself

Comment: server response, the error was invalid parameters

Comment: the respond just mean the api cant understand my request, i want a better format for my code pls

Comment: Than it's nothing to do with android. Could you provide link to server API documentation and also specify full request including HTTP method used and endpoint.

Comment: am sorry i cant provide the link to the api, what i want is how to send a request to a server that will be in the format, kindly help me pls

Answer (score 1):

Use `JsonObject` instead of: creating a `Map`, converting it to `Byte[]` and then getting its `String.valueOf(...)`.
This will allow you to send your complete object as body of the request, instead of the incomplete body that is being sent right now: `{"amount":"000","card":"[B@a2e...."}`)

The problem with the value that is being sent for `"card"`: `"[B@a2e...."` is that it's not a representation of your object with its properties. Instead, it is only the memory address of the Byte Array you created.

In your code, use `JsonObject` for your objects and only do the conversion to `Byte[]` at the end of `getBody()` method, since that is the place where you finally return your complete object:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Authorization", User_Token);
    // headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");  // This is probably redundant, as you are already setting it on getBodyContentType()
    return headers;
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return "application/json";
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("amount", amount);
        jsonObject.put("card", come());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonObject.toString().getBytes();
}

private JSONObject come() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    params.put( "number", number);
    params.put( "expiry_month", month);
    params.put( "expiry_year", year);
    params.put( "cvv", cvv);
    params.put( "pin", pin);
    return params;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing the request to your service using postman, curl or some other tool?

Comment: Am using postmn,  it work perfectly on postman,the other guz writing the web is  done.this is the link https//:api.myflex. ng/wallet/fund

Comment: @kehindehussein According to [docs](http://docs.myflex.ng/) there is no `wallet/fund` specified. Where did you get specification of this end point?

Answer (score 0):

In case you need exact format you need to make sure that values of `number`,`month` etc, are passed as strings but not integers. 
Also to make code look shorter and less destructive you could chain `put` calls. Here is a bit refactored version:

```
@Override
public byte[] getBody() {  
    try {
        final JSONObject card = new JSONObject()
                .put("number", String.valueOf(number))
                .put("expiry_month", String.valueOf(month))
                .put("expiry_year", String.valueOf(year))
                .put("cvv", String.valueOf(cvv))
                .put("pin", String.valueOf(pin));

        return new JSONObject()
                .put("amount", String.valueOf(amount))
                .put("card", card)
                .toString()
                .getBytes();    
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Empty json return will not help us as in this case 
    //we will send useless empty body to the server. 
    return null;
}
```

I don't know what on caller side of `getBody()` is happening and whether or not you are able to modify that code. But you need somehow to track that `null` return or instead introduce your own exception class that should be checked on `getBody()` caller side. But in case you have no control over `getBody()` caller side you need return some non `null`, empty return:

```
    return new byte[0];
```

Comment: it give the same error "invalid parameters" pls help me out

Comment: The code I've provided should generate JSON object with the same structure as you requested. If the server respond with "invalid parameters" how could we help you without knowing what server expects and what not?

Comment: This is the api link https//:api.myflex.ng/wallet/fund